# Lombok in java module contributing to method count in apk

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, lombok

I'm using Lombok in a pure-java module inside an Android Studio project. This is the build.gradle for the module:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    providedCompile "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.6"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
}
```

However when I build my android module the resulting APK has these method counts from lombok, when it should have none.

```
lombok: 4099
        bytecode: 85
        core: 308
            debug: 18
            handlers: 8
            runtimeDependencies: 15
        delombok: 253
            ant: 22
        eclipse: 820
            agent: 223
            handlers: 387
        experimental: 16
        extern: 6
            apachecommons: 1
            java: 1
            log4j: 2
            slf4j: 2
        installer: 286
            eclipse: 109
        javac: 970
            apt: 132
            handlers: 317
            java6: 24
            java7: 24
            java8: 26
        libs: 996
            com: 61
                zwitserloot: 61
                    cmdreader: 61
            org: 935
                objectweb: 935
                    asm: 935
                        commons: 405
                        signature: 41
                        tree: 199
        patcher: 316
            equinox: 18
            inject: 7
            scripts: 150
```

Is this something wrong w/ lombok, how I'm using `providedCompile` or something with the Android/Gradle build system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [compileOnly](https://gradle.org/blog/compile-only-dependencies/) instead.

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer and not a gradle expert.

Comment: Excellent. I had to upgrade my gradle wrapper to 2.12 which was an easy change in `gradle-wrapper.properties` This also meant I didn't need `war` plugin. It turns out that my `app` Android module was piggy backing this dependency in my pure-java module, so I had to set a dependency in it's `build.gradle` file too: `provided "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.6"`